# Use the public GitHub API to get all merged pull requests in a JSON format

Tags: url, github, github-api

I am trying to get all the **closed and merged** commits on a certain repository using the github API (https://api.github.com/), and the only way I have found to do this is to check for commits that are closed (`api.github.com/repos/user/repo/pulls?state=closed`), then make sure the `merged_at` is not equal to `null`, but this is a slow way to do it. Is there a way to make github check if the PR is closed and has been merged at the same time directly in the url? Something like `api.github.com/repos/user/repo/pulls?state=closed?is_merged=true`? And return all the PRs matching the criteria?

NOTE: this has nothing to do with the `/repos/user/repo/pulls/pr_id/merge`, because that only tells you if a **single** pull request is merged, and does not search everywhere in the list of PRs.

Answer (score 2):

### Request template

```sh
curl \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
https://api.github.com/search/issues\?q\=repo:{repo_owner}/{repo}+is:pr+is:merged
```

### Explanation:

You can't get merged pull requests by std Github API **/pulls** route. But you can do this using Search API.
More info in docs:

- Use Search API: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search#about-the-search-api
- More tricks for search issues and prs: https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests

Answer (score 0):

You can use the “is:merged” operator in your search query
Check this out: https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-based-on-the-state-of-an-issue-or-pull-request

Comment: but this is not API query. The OP was interested in API calls